# How to open a file in Eclipse like it was a XML

Tags: xml, eclipse, styles

I'm programming on Eclipse Enviroment and I'm working with a special files with a special extension. They are a cutom XML files in the company where I'm working. Eclipse doesm't recognize this types of files and they are show like they was plain text. How can I open that files with the XML style?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single file you can right click on the file and select 'Open With > XML Editor'. Eclipse remembers which editor you use so you only have to do this once. If 'XML Editor' is not in the list, select 'Other...' and select it from the list displayed in the dialog.

You can also set up a file association by opening the Preferences and going to 'General > Editors > File associations. Here you can add your file extension and select the editor to use.

Comment: Hi .. first of all thanks for your anwer Greg. I did what you said there but that was not what I'm looking for. I mean, I can open a file with the XML editor but the text don't shows th XML style. The custom XML tags, comments, special word don't take the style of a common XML.

Comment: Are these files actually properly formed XML? The XML editor won't work with anything that is not correct XML.

Comment: Well, it is a customized XML in my company and I know tha it is possible because I saw it in my coworkers eclipse enviroment.

Comment: Are you sure it is opening in the XML editor? If you have previously opened the file with the plain text editor you will have to use 'Open With' once even if you set the file associations.

Comment: Ok that was ... after file associations must specify the XML Editor in the Open With option because that open a dialog to set de Content Type that define the style of the text. So if any other wants to do the same must associate the files and associate also the Content Type Thank you veruy much Greg

Answer (score 4):

Follow the below Steps

1. Right Click on the XML File in the Eclipse
2. You Should See 'Open With' option and click that
3. Then select 'Xml Editor'
4. 'XMl Editor' opens in 2 modes
   (1) Source
   (2) Design
5. Look at the Left bottom of the for the Source | Design buttons
6. Click Source and there you are!

Most of the time it Opens in Design Mode where you can't edit

Answer (score -1):

Right click the xml file in Eclipse -> open with-> text editor. Then you can see the XML style.

Comment: That will treat the file as a plain text. I think the intent of the OP was to have it opened in XML editor

Comment: 'I mean, I can open a file with the XML editor but the text don't shows the XML style' , I just saw this comment from previous answer. I guess what he wanted is to open file and modify it. I also tried it with xml editor, but it doesn't work. Then I tried with text editor, it worked and I can also copy the content of xml file.